# What do the $ and { } meaning in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

can anyone explain **$P{p_date}** do in this SQL. I have to rebuild SQL query but unfortunately my previous coworker doesn't make any comment about it. So, I don't understand the code below:

```
SELECT * FROM table_A AINNER JOIN table_B BON (A.key = B.keyAND A.date = $P{p_date});
```

I think it maybe pass date value to in Oracle but I'm not sure.

Comment: While there is some extremely unusual Oracle SQL syntax that uses `$`, `{`, and `}`, your code is most likely using those characters for some sort of external macro from another programming language or environment. How is your SQL being executed? Is it called in a PHP page, a Crystal Report, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That most likely comes from a reporting tool such as Jasper Reports or similar.

In any case, it is simply saying that this query will receive a value from a user at run time, thus your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_A A 
INNER JOIN table_B B 
ON (A.key = B.keyAND A.date = <some user provided value>);
```